# Math floor JavaScript is not adding

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am trying to make a place where you type in a number that is between 1-8 in four different boxes and it adds up the total and the page says "Your total point is _____ ". However, for example, if I enter in 2 in all the boxes the result is '2222'.

I tried this:`

```
<form onsubmit="calculatetotal(event)">
event.preventDefault()
<p11>math</p10><input class=" w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green "; type="number" id="a" value="a" required><br><br>
<p11>sci</p10><input class=" w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green";  type="number" id="b" value="b"required><br><br>
<p11>English</p10><input class=" w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green";  type="number" id="c" value="c"required><br><br>
<p11>MTL/HMTL</p10><input class=" w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green";  type="number" id="d"            value="d" required><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<h6 id="demo2"></h6>

<script>
function calculatetotal(event) {

let M = document.getElementById("a").value;
let sci = document.getElementById("b").value;
let el = document.getElementById("c").value;
let mt = document.getElementById("d").value;

// calculation for total al points
let total = Math.floor(M + sci + el + mt);
//results
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Your total point is " + total;


}

</script>`
```

Can someone help me correct the math.floor

Answer (score -3):

The issue with your code is that the values obtained from the input fields are treated as strings, not numbers. When you use the `+` operator with strings, it performs string concatenation instead of addition. That's why you are getting '2222' as the result when you input '2' in all the boxes.

To fix this, you need to convert the input values to numbers before performing the addition. You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert the string values to integers or floating-point numbers, respectively. Here's the updated code:

```html
<form onsubmit="calculatetotal(event)">
  <!-- Input fields with proper value attribute -->
  <p11>math</p10><input class="w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green" type="number" id="a" value="0" required><br><br>
  <p11>sci</p10><input class="w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green" type="number" id="b" value="0" required><br><br>
  <p11>English</p10><input class="w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green" type="number" id="c" value="0" required><br><br>
  <p11>MTL/HMTL</p10><input class="w3-border w3-round w3-hover-green" type="number" id="d" value="0" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<h6 id="demo2"></h6>

<script>
  function calculatetotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Move this inside the function
    let M = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
    let sci = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
    let el = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
    let mt = parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value);

    // calculation for total points
    let total = M + sci + el + mt;
    
    // results
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Your total point is " + total;
  }
</script>
```

In this updated code, I've removed the `value` attributes from the input fields as they are not necessary in this context. I've also used `parseInt` to convert the input values to integers before adding them together. Now, the total will be calculated correctly based on the user input.

Comment: Thanks! But what is 'parseInt'?

Comment: parseInt is a built-in JavaScript function that is used to parse a string and convert it into an integer

`let numberString = "42";
let number = parseInt(numberString);

console.log(number); // Output: 42`

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT